# Filter objects in DataGrip

Tags: sql-server, datagrip

How to filter objects in DataGrip like we filter in SQL server management studio?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Context menu on datasource
2. SCHEMAS tab
3. There you will find a string field where you can specify a filter.[image]